# MSDEPLOY - Migrate IIS6 - IIS8 and change content path from c:\inetpub\wwroot

Tags: iis-6, iis-8, msdeploy

I’m currently trying to migrate an iis6 (server 2003) websites to iis8 (sever 2012R2).

All the content is currently residing on: C:\Inetpub\wwwroot. There are over a hundred web applications under the “Default Web Site”

On the IIS6 server I’m using web deploy 2.1 and on the ii8 server I’m using web deploy 3.6.

During the sync process in **STEP 2** below, I would like to move the content from the C:\inetpub\wwwroot to d:\inetpub\wwwroot. Please help with the correct switches and statements to use to accomplish this.

I need a solution that has been tried and trued and is not just theory based.

**STEP 1:**

msdeploy -verb:sync -source:webserver60,computername=MyServerName -enableLink:AppPoolExtension -dest:package=c:\migration\ migration.zip,encryptPassword=xyz

On the destination I then do the reverse, but need to know what to use to change the content root path:

**STEP 2:**

msdeploy -verb:sync -source:package=p:\migration\migration.zip,encryptPassword=xyz -enableLink:AppPoolExtension -dest:auto,computername=MyNewServer

Answer (score 0):

In theory you could take the archive.xml file (which is similar to a manifest file) from within the package you created and copy it to a new file then rename to destManifest.xml.  Then search for and change the paths you want.  You will also need to remove all the extra MSDeploy xml attributes.

In step 2 set the destination to the manifest like so:

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:package=p:\migration\migration.zip,encryptPassword=xyz -enableLink:AppPoolExtension -dest:manifest=[path to dest manifest],computername=MyNewServer
```

I believe this could achieve what your wanting but its a lot of manual work and troubleshooting on the dest manifest file.